# What is the meaning of "of being ~ " in the following sentence?

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of "of being ~ " in the sentence,

> My son and I were just kicked out ***of being a FULTON COUNTY poll
> worker***.

?

Does "My son and I were just kicked out of being a FULTON COUNTY poll worker" mean "My son and I were just expelled from a place, even though my son and I were a FULTON COUNTY poll worker" ?

Comment: they were kicked out of the *position* of being a poll worker in Fulton County, not out of any particular place.

Comment: **Of being** doesn't mean anything. They were (kicked out of) (being a poll worker) - though, as there were two of them, surely it should be _being poll workers_?

Comment: Interestingly, the reason for them being "removed" as CNN calls it, is because a social media post surfaced showing them attending the Jan. 6, 2021, attack on the US Capitol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like unprepared speech from native speakers of a non-standard variety of American English. If this person had had time to prepare their words, they likely wouldn't have said it this way.

This person is using the phrasal verb "kick s.o. out of" *in a non-standard way*. Normally, it means to remove someone from a location, but here it's used to mean remove someone from a position.